# Use cached libsass binary when installing grunt-sass

Tags: node-sass, libsass

I have lots of projects that use `grunt-sass`, which depends on `node-sass`, which depends on `libsass`. Everytime I checkout one of those projects from the their git repository and `npm install` them, `libsass` is compiled again and in my computer, this process takes a lot of time.

`node-sass` has ways of providing an existing `libsass` binary, so I don't have to go through the process of compiling it everytime. (https://github.com/sass/node-sass#binary-configuration-parameters)

I tried then installing globally a `node-sass` npm package. It compiles libsass and install it in my `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass` folder:

`npm install -g node-sass`

after I set a `sass_binary_path` parameter in my `~/.npmrc` file:

`sass_binary_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-47/binding.node`

When I `npm install` my projects after checkout them, libsass isn't compiled anymore and the installation is successful. **But when I execute a grunt task which uses grunt-sass, here's what I get:**

```
Loading "sass.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '~/dev/my-project/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
Warning: Task "sass:dist" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What am I doing wrong in this process of caching `libsass`?

--

EDIT:

When I install `npm install` using the normal process, node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-47/binding.node is created. When I try to use the node-sass cache flags, it doesn't even create the `node_modules/node-sass/vendor` folder.

Comment: I'm not sure libsass is your issue.  What does your .scss file look like ?  Any references to  vendor ?

Comment: No, there is no reference to this vendor directory inside `node_modules/node-sass`. When I install using the normal process, `node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-47/binding.node` is created. When I try to use the node-sass cache flags, it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use a cached `node-sass` library finally.

First a binary package should be downloaded from: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

Then I used a environment variable to point to this binary.

```
export SASS_BINARY_PATH="$HOME/dev/bin/darwin-x64-47_binding.node"
```

When installing node-sass with npm, it uses the provided binary.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent caching is coming in https://github.com/sass/node-sass/pull/1714 (probably version 3.11), I just need to fix up the PR.